# Python, Windows: The term 'conda' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

Tags: python, windows, powershell, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I am facing an issue with the Windows 10 Powershell. Whenever I open it I get an error:

```
& : The term 'C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. 
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.

At C:\Users\hp\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:4 char:4
+ (& "C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "hook ...
+    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\hp\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe:String) [], CommandNotFoundExce
   ption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Previously I had installed anaconda and vs code to work in python but later I uninstalled anaconda and downloaded python3 from `https://www.python.org/downloads/`.

I have added the environment variables for Python in Path but still I get this error in the Powershell.

How to fix this?

Comment: Wait so do you need conda or the regular python interpreter or both?

Comment: I need a python interpreter.

Comment: If you can decide between conda and python depending on your use case I could help you to setup one of them

Comment: Most of my work is associated with Data Analysis and building Machine Learning and Deep Learning Models, I am using vs code for the first time, can you suggest what will be better conda or python? @dopewind

Comment: For Machine Learning I would definitely recommend conda as it has many in-build libraries for Python specially built for machine learning.

Comment: Okay, then please help me with it's setup.

Comment: I have posted an answer which should work, if it doesn't please do let me know so that I can edit it with fix for what went wrong

Comment: Okay, I will work on it and let you know.

Comment: @Ishan Dutta -Could you select the conda environment in the lower left corner of VS Code? Have you tried using the 'cmd' terminal in VS Code? For the conda environment in VS Code, you can refer to: [Conda environments in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_conda-environments).

Answer (score 0):

Try using Anaconda Prompt instead, it has the "conda" command

Answer (score -1):

Uninstall any other python interpreter installation and restart to refresh env variables

Download Anaconda Installer from [here](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows)

You should add it to PATH if you want to use it outside of Anaconda Navigator and I recommend you install it systemwide with admin privilege

[image: Installation screen]

[image: Installation 2]

This should add conda executable to PATH allowing it to be called systemwide